# Google App Engine index inconsistent hours after put

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm having a consistency problem on App Engine I'm not sure how to address. I've performed a query, selected an entity from the result, edited it and saved. All, using the low level Java API.

Performing an Entity Key query on the edited item, returns the updated version. However performing an indexed query by a certain property of this entity, returns the old version.

I've originally considered this as an occasionally expected "eventually consistent" HRD issue. However, I'm now hours after the original save, and this is still the case.

Ridiculously enough (and perhaps not so surprising), this occurs even when using the Datastore Viewer in the App Engine console: A GQL query returns a row with stale data, and selecting the entity opens the updated data.

What can I do? This sounds like an index bug. Is there a way to "refresh" the Index?

Comment: Eventual consistency takes a few seconds at most. Since no one is reporting the same problem (I never saw this behavior myself), I doubt that this is an App Engine bug. Maybe if you can post some code/screenshots, we can figure out what is going on.

Comment: I was wrong: it looks like something is going on: https://groups.google.com/forum/?show_docid=fae072cf1c7db8b1#!topic/google-appengine/dRUabeuAoRo

Comment: Thanks. Things are apparently back to normal. I would love to get Google's comments on the matter... This is actually worse than getting a put failure in some cases. It's very difficult, if not impossible, to create a design that assumes eventual consistency that isn't in a reasonable time frame.

Comment: You can also check on their status tracker page: https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/appengine/15010